# Как автоматизировать создание базы данных и таблиц?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Нужно создать БД с таблицами. После создания БД мне нужно добавлять новые таблицы в БД, новые столбцы. Требуется, чтобы создание БД с таблицами делалось с помощью скрипта. Как автоматизировать создание базы данных и таблиц?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создание таблиц автоматизируется т.н. DDL (Data Definition Language) - часть стандарта SQL

Начните со [статьи в википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) - там ничего сложного нет